# Matrix of a linear mapping question

Tags: matrices

I'm attempting a question  that states

Let L : R3 → R3 be the linear mapping defined by

$$L(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(2x_1 −x_2,x_2 +x_3,x_3 −3x_1)
$$

and it wants me to find $$[L]$$

is this just the array of the linear mapping? Would it be this
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2x_1 - x_2 \\
x_2 + x_3 \\
x_3 - 3x_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

or something else?

Comment: N, it is the matrix represenation of the endomorphism, i. e., the3×3  matrix $A$ such that when you apply A to the column vector $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$, you get what you 've written.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$L$ will be the $3 \times 3$ array

$$L = \begin{pmatrix}L_{11}&L_{12}&L_{13}\\L_{21}&L_{22}&L_{23}\\L_{31}&L_{32}&L_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$ such that

$$L = \begin{pmatrix}L_{11}&L_{12}&L_{13}\\L_{21}&L_{22}&L_{23}\\L_{31}&L_{32}&L_{33}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}2x_1 - x_2 \\ x_2 + x_3 \\ x_3 - 3x_1\end{pmatrix}.$$

One way to find it would be to figure out what $L$ does to each standard basis vector $e_i$.

A small example. Let's say we want the matrix for the transformation $(x_1, x_2) \overset{T}{\longmapsto} (3x_1 - 5x_2, x_1 + 3x_2)$. Using the template above, we'll represent our transformation $T$ as a matrix $[T]$, where

$$[T]\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}T_{11} &T_{12} \\T_{21} & T_{22} \end{pmatrix}{x_1 \choose x_2} = {T_{11}x_1 + T_{12}x_2 \choose T_{21}x_1 + T_{22}x_2} = {3x_1 - 5x_2 \choose x_1 + 3x_2},$$

which means our matrix will be $[T] = \begin{pmatrix}3 & -5 \\1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$, which will indeed send the vector ${ x_1 \choose x_2}$ to ${3x_1 -5x_2 \choose x_1 + 3x_2}$, just like we want.

Comment: The standard basis vectors would be (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) right? (I'm fairly new to matrices as i know this is probably a noob question)

Comment: @James Yep, those are the ones. It might even be more illustrative to do the fully general calculations (with $L_{ij}$ and $x_k$) to see what each of the $L_{ij}$ has to be, in order to get the vector you're looking for; the basis vectors might be more helpful once your'e more familiar with everything.

Comment: could you elaborate more on what i'm actually supposed to do in order to solve the question? I'm still kinda lost.

would I be doing
$$
L(1, 0, 0) = 2x_1-x_2 = 2(1) - 0 \\
L(0, 1, 0) = x_2 + x_3 = 1 + 0 \\
L(0, 0, 1) = x_3 - 3x_1 = 1 - 0 \\
$$
or something else?

Comment: @James If you think about doing the matrix multiplication, the first entry in the result would be $L_{11}x_1 + L_{12}x_2 + L_{13}x_3$, which needs to be the same as $2x_1 - x_2$, right? Does that help at all?

Comment: Still confused. Do I need to find an $$ L_11, L_12, ...., L_33 $$ such that it works?

Comment: @James Yes, exactly. You need to represent that transformation as a $3\times 3$ matrix, for which you'll need those $9$ entries. And when you multiply your matrix, $L$, by the vector $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, it should give you that result. I'll edit an example into my post.

Comment: @James Example added, hopefully it helps.

Comment: would that mean [L] would be the following matrix? Is this the solution?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-3 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @James Yep, that's the one! And if you look at the first column there, it's exactly $L(1, 0, 0)$, that was my other hint about using the standard basic vectors. Nicely done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ so that $$L(x) = \pmatrix{2x_1 - x_2\\x_2 + x_3\\-3x_1+x_3} = A\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{2&-1&0\\0&1&1\\-3&0&1}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3}.   $$